# How can i capture the css code execution on chrome devtools timeline?

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools

my code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<title>dom</title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="keywords" content="">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/test.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="test"></div>
    <div class="test2"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I try to capture the css code execution on chrome devtools timeline,but come to nothing.
So what should I do?

---

I find how to capture the css code "execution" details and when it happens.
According to [this article](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/simplify-paint-complexity-and-reduce-paint-areas?hl=en-us),you should check the "paint" box to capture:

> There’s an option in the Chrome DevTools timeline which will give you
>   more information: a paint profiler. To enable it, go to the Timeline
>   and check the “Paint” box at the top.

and the paint happened after the "parse author style sheet" event:
[image: css paint]

This is my first question on stackoverflow,thanks for everyone helping me.

Comment: You can't. CSS is not programming language, it's just a group of rules for styling.

Comment: `width:100px` will make the div.test 100px,so css code must do something,and how could i capture the 'something'?i'm curious about the process,and especially when it happens.

Answer (score 1):

CSS is not an imperative language, it does not "execute" per se. The CSS rules are applied, though, when either stylesheet contents or DOM structure change. The "Style Recalculate" event on the Timeline indicates the time renderer spends calculating and applying styles based on CSS rules to individual render objects produced from the DOM nodes. The details of the event provide information on how many nodes were affected.

Comment: thx for your concept,but I find the relevant paint after "parse author style sheet" event,instead of "style recalculate".My chrome version is 44.0.2403.155 (64-bit) for mac.

Comment: Parse Author Style Sheet (which is "Parse Stylesheet" in the most recent version BTW) is somewhat different -- that's, duh, just parsing the stylesheets, i.e. converting them to internal style model representation as their text content is received.

Comment: In the particular case show on your screenshot, you seem to have "Forced Layout" warning in your onload event handler, I would expect style recalculation to happen as part of this, i.e. within the load event handler.

Comment: thanks for correcting my statement!
And I hope you can correct my pool english statement too ^^

I will give you a deserved upvote when I have 15 rep.